# Generating files with VITE based on an environment variable

Tags: vite, rollup

I am creating lib using Vite. My library imports a json config file

```
import config from "./config.json";

const getConfig = () => {
  return config;
};
```

The contents of config.json will be generated based on the environment variables. The variables are sensitive so I would prefer to not use the "VITE_" prefix

So far I have the following, but this isn't ideal as it creates the file in "src/config.json" which could be committed to source control. Is there a method with vite/rollup to transforms a file based on environment variables.

```
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");
  // custom function that creates src/config.json
  generateConfig(env.secretValue);
  return {
    build: {
      lib: {
        entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
        name: "my-lib",
        fileName: "my-lib",
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      dts({
        exclude: ["src/config-generator/*"],
      }),
    ],
    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(env.APP_ENV),
    },
  };
});
```